# Which letter is the most compressible in the English alphabet?

Tags: http, compression, ip, gzip, alphabetical

I have to send minimal (location) data to a server from a mobile device. For convenience reasons (PHP-compatibility) I don't just send it as a raw query string or post data, I send it as a variable for example:

```
a=12345,6789
```

The question is, which letter should I choose (as the name of the variable instead of `a`) if I want to be a good neighbor on the internet and create the most compressible chunk of data (as some hops may use gzip or other compression).

---

**Edit**
(For all the naysayers out there).

The amount of compression achievable depend on the bit stream itself. A total random bit stream (with the lowest possible entropy) is the least compressible. A uniform bit stream (all zeroes or all ones) is the most.

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail why you think the choice of letter makes any difference to anything?

Comment: I'd suggest an uppercase I in a sans serif font. That is clearly the simplest letter.

Comment: @BNL are you serious? AFAIK, there is no font involved.

Comment: @submachine Well, if font is not involved, then I would go with a lowercase o. A circle is crazy compressible.

Comment: @aix, You might want to edit the subject line. The word 'English' seems to be the root of all the confusion with the 'naysayers'. It is true that compression is language agnostic. And like you said, it is also true that compression depends on the data being compressed, and so the choice of character can affect compression (very slightly).

Comment: @submachine I used "English alphabet" because variable names (identifiers) usually have to start with these. Any you're right, the title itself is ambiguous but if you read the question itself it should be clear that I'm talking about this on context of a HTTP request (php-compatibility).

Comment: @BNL: Are you sure that the uppercase letter *i* is more compressible than the lowercase letter *el*? I think this calls for some comparative benchmarks. ;-)

Comment: I would like to have a single explanation why is this "not a real question" please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, gzip is based on huffman coding => Frequently occuring characters are the cheapest upon compression. So you should probably use the character that occurs most frequently in your POST data.

If 'a=12345,6789' is the *only* content you post, I don't think it matters what character you choose for the variable name. On the other hand, if you post a bigger chunk of content, then using a character that occurs frequently in that content would be the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to outsmart gzip.  There is no single "best" choice, first, and second that data is not English language data anyway.  Read how gzip compresses stuff here: http://www.gzip.org/deflate.html  the upshot of which is that it will figure out how to encode the data you give it optimally.  If it follows the pattern gzip expects, it will use that pattern, but it can also build an optimal encoding for that block and use that.

Don't worry about this.  Spend your time figuring out how to send fewer requests, and you'll overall get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. Compression algorithms are usually language-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

The compressibility of letters does not depend on their value as such - the dictionary is built during compression.

So "aaaaaaa" should be as compressible as "nnnnnnn", while "anaanannnan" is not as compressible due to its chaotic pattern.